# Iranian student with Hungarian residency permit staying in Italy for more than 90 days

Tags: italy, study

I'm an Iranian student studying in Hungary with a 2-year residency permit. I have a project in Italy, which would take around 5 months. I came to Italy from Hungary on March 1st. Do you think I can leave Italy after 90 days and then come back again? Or is there any way to do this without asking for an Italian residency permit?

Comment: I think a tourist visa might work for you. Italy usually grants citizens of my country a visa that is valid for a year or six months. However, the situation might vary from a country to another. For instance, France grants us a tourist visa that is valid as long as the passport is valid but a person from North Africa told me that he got a tourist visa that is valid exactly for the duration he wrote in the application plus few weeks, he had to present to them airline tickets and confirmed booking.

Answer (score 6):

The EU residence permit granted by a Schengen State will allow you to reside in another Schengen State for up to 90 days. To stay longer you must apply for a national residence permit from the other Member State.

Foreigners who intend to stay in Italy for more than three months must apply for a residence permit. These permits allow foreigners to stay in Italy, under certain conditions depending on the category of the permit.

Regardless of whether expats apply for a working residence permit before or after they have arrived (the ability to do so depends on their nationality), they will have to report to their local immigration centre.

ON [http://ec.europa.eu](http://ec.europa.eu/immigration/who-does-what/what-does-the-eu-do/already-in-the-eu_en)

> **Moving between EU countries during my long-term stay – more than three months**
>
> When you stay in an EU country for a long stay, usually for more than
>   three months, you will generally be issued with a national long-stay
>   visa and/or a residence permit.
>
> If your long-stay visa or permit has been issued by a Schengen area
>   country, you can travel to another Schengen area country for three
>   months per six-month period. You must:
>
> - justify the purpose of your stay;
> - have sufficient financial resources for your stay and return;
> - not be considered a threat to public policy, public security or public health.
>
> You can also pass through other Schengen area countries on the way to
>   your host country.
>
> To move from one Schengen area country to another for more than three
>   months, you will need a long-term visa and/or a permit for that
>   country. If you wish to work, study or join your family in the second
>   country, you may have to fulfil more national conditions. To travel to
>   a country that is not in the borderless Schengen area, you must get a
>   separate national visa and meet all the necessary conditions.

...

> Do you think i can leave italy after 90 days and then come back again
>   ?

The answer is no, at least not in 6 months period. Italy has really strict immigration, so if you try you run a good chance of being detected. You might get lucky, but you might also get fined (it's a federal offense) and there have also been cases where people were imprisoned.

Answer (score 2):

A third-country national holding a valid Hungarian residence permit has the right of entry without a visa and the right of residence in the territory of Schengen Member States not exceeding ninety days within a one hundred and eighty day period. Unfortunately, if you want to stay longer in Italy you need to apply for residence permit.
For a residency permit, you need to verify the followings:

(1) Verifying the Purpose of the Residence

(2) Verifying Sufficient Financial Resources

(3) Verifying Sufficient Accommodation

(4) Health Insurance

(5) Documents evidencing the conditions of the exit

How you can do this: ( if you need more information, please check our website: https://www.immigrationlawyershungary.com/residencepermit)

(1) Verifying the Purpose of the Residence

The purpose of your residence could be: Work, visit, study, business, etc. You can verify it any reliable means.

(2) Verifying Sufficient Financial Resources 
You can verify it with bank account statement, work contract, tax statement etc.

(3) Verifying Sufficient Accommodation 
Rent contract, Proof on dormitory service, paid hotel booking, real estate purchase document, contract on accommodation by courtesy etc. can verify it.

(4) Health Insurance

A foreign, Hungarian or Italian insurance policy could be good. You can buy your health insurance in Hungary too. 
The cost is about 200 € /year.

(5) Documents evidencing the conditions of the exit

You have to attach a statement to the application undertaking that you voluntary leave the EU if the application is refused or the permit is expired. 
Your passport has to be valid until the end of the permit plus 90 more days. You have to have either a valid ticket to return or sufficient funds to purchase such a ticket.
If you need more information or any advice, please check our website: https://www.immigrationlawyershungary.com/home
https://www.immigrationlawyershungary.com/studyvisa

Comment: Welcome to Expats.SE. While we allow some [self promotion](https://expatriates.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131/self-promotion-on-the-site), please consider making contributions that do not include self promotional material.